# Proper separation of an aggregate in a saga

Tags: oop, architecture, microservices, domain-driven-design

I need to develop a basket for my service. I have a service called *Service1* responsible for digital products bought by customers. I also have another service called *Billing* responsible for prices and discounts. Now I am seeking the right way to create basket without strong coupling between these two services, because preparing a basket and validating the products within it requires a lot of data from Service1.

My first approach was making the basket a part of the Billing service thereby obviating interactions with other services. It makes it easier to calculate the price of the products in a basket and apply discounts. However, when a user needs to renew products or buy additional services for existing products, several problems arise: for example, before adding an existing product to the basket, numerous business rules have to be validated that depend on the product type and other conditions, which results in significant coupling between services. Moreover, a user can delete a product from their panel after adding it to the basket but before checkout, requiring me to remove the product from the basket in Billing service as well.

In an alternative approach, I plan to introduce a *saga* where the basket operations are divided across both Service1 and Billing. The Billing service will be the primary service that will invoke the saga upon a request, creating a basket aggregate instance in Billing and another in Service1. This allows us to validate the billing and Service1 parts separately, reducing coupling.

If a user deletes a product or an administrator locks a user's product due to rule violations, a product aggregate will create an event listened to by Service1-basket aggregate. The Service1-basket will generate an event that will be listened to by billing-basket aggregate.

I prefer the saga approach more, but I'm concerned that all the data required for checkout is located in the Billing part of the basket, while the Service1 part is only required for validation. Is this a normal situation, or not?

Are my thoughts correct, or is there another way to resolve this problem?

Comment: First, specify which types of users do each of these actions—customer, salesman, admin, etc.  It's ambiguous what you just asked. Second, rename Service1. Name it correctly. It's hard to track what you ask.

Comment: A basket is a temporary concept that is read-only. Some would implement it on the client side in cookies. You don't need to include data in the basket management. Put the related IDs of other aggregates in it. All rules should apply when finalizing or fetching the basket. No events are needed.

Comment: But if you need to persist it, as I said, you can apply rules on fetching or finalizing the basket.

Comment: Basket is not temporary concept in my case. User can add new and existing products to the basket and do checkout for one week. But also manager can generate basket with products for a client and make checkout to create bill for client. Also if user has periodical payments for his products basket and checkout it's happening automatically.

Let's call service1 as Panel.

If basket was created by the user, he can edit it. For example change payment period or count of additional services. So basket has unique ID.

Comment: Discounts  are  depends  on  count  of  products  and their types. For example discount can be for first year of product if this product user will buy with product of other type. Because of this each item of my basket should include a lot of information: period, price, product_id(if this is renew), productType..

Comment: Now validation of the basket validating on adding new item to basket and before checkout. it's allow me to be sure that product available for checkout over time. Moreover, when user purchasing a product, we interact with an external service to clarify availability.

Comment: Can a user own multiple baskets?

Comment: Can  be  only  one  basket  which managed by user. If order created by manager or automatically, we creating temporary basket for user, add products and services to it and do checkout. After that temporary basket will be deleted.

But no matter who created basket it must be validated before checkout.